# Bash script question - skip enter key press

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Here is a portion of my script:

```
read main_menu

case "$main_menu" in

    "0" )   exit
            ;;
    "1" )   cp /etc/bamt/cgminer.conf.X11 /etc/bamt/cgminer.conf;
            sudo mine restart;
            ;;
```

How can I make it so after the user enters 0 or 1, 2 etc, he doesn't have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? Practically, when you enter the number it would directly jump to the next menu or function without the needing to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Can you help me implement it here?

```
while :
do
    echo -e "\n Test script"
    echo -e "\t (0) Exit"
    echo -e "\t (1) Option 1"
    echo -n "Enter choice:"
      read main_menu
      case "$main_menu" in
         "0" ) exit
         ;;
         "1" ) exit
         ;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash `read` supports a [number of options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read), among them `-n 1`:

```
$ read -n 1 main_menu
1$ echo $main_menu
1
```

The `-n` option means that:

> read returns after reading *nchars* characters rather than waiting for a complete line of input, but honor a delimiter if fewer than *nchars* characters are read before the delimiter.

`-n 1` tells `read` to return after reading a single character of input, so as soon as the user presses <kbd>1</kbd> then `read` will stop and save the input into the variable.